Is it possible to use Nav2 Low Level Controllers without a map?
I am currently building a car-like robot and wrote a simple pure-pursuit controller. I found that Nav2 has a really nice implementation of it. Since my robot does not compute an occupancy grid, but estimates the global path through other means, I was wondering if somebody had some experience using only parts of the Nav2 stack separately. I assume that I could somehow write my own map plugin that converts my path to a costmap, but that seems to somehow defeat the purpose of that. I saw the Simple Commander API from Nav2, but to my understanding this still needs a map.

This is not directly possible with nav2. You can simply supply an empty map, but that can be a bit clunky and as you said, defeats the purpose. I had the same issue, so what I did was write my own nav2_core for an interface without a costmap for both, planner plugins and controller plugins. And then write my own plugins for that and write my own planner_server and controller_server.
However, You don't even have to go the plugin way. It is completely sufficient to write your own controller_server and planner_server and put all your functionality in there directly. This can then be nicely integrated with all nav2 functionalities, like navigator, BT servers, smoother, etc.
It does require some direct interface with the API, but it felt quite straight forward.
